# Pagination control changes value of model it is bound to to 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

As demonstrated in the code below, the existence of a pagination (from the Angular Directives for Bootstrap library) control changes the value of the model to 1 on the initial load, is there any way around this? I have added a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBXC1AAUxT03Pnd3llIe?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <pagination ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>    
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<script>
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var testCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.currentPage = 4;

    $scope.$watch('currentPage', function(){
        alert($scope.currentPage);
    });
}

testCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
testApp.controller('testCtrl', testCtrl);
</script>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post a demo demonstrating your issue.  according to the docs and this plunker it works as you expect setting the current page to 4:  http://plnkr.co/edit/mBJMyohp1JQI3LBqRLkr?p=preview

Comment: The code provided above is a full demo, but I'll copy it into a plunkr for convenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is you aren't specifing the total number of pages.  Try adding `total-items="totalItems"` to your directive and the directive defaults to 10 items per page.  If you only have 10 items it will only show 1.   You also need to set the number of items per page.

```
 <pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>   

var testCtrl = function($scope) {
   $scope.currentPage = 4;
   $scope.totalItems = 10;
   $scope.itemPerPage =1;

   $scope.$watch('currentPage', function(){
    alert($scope.currentPage);
   });
 }
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mZsBhzpA5lax883C5ihy?p=preview

Comment: Still the same sadly, I had this initially (in my actual production code) and took it out for the purposes of the example as it made no difference

Comment: Bizarre, works fine on the plunker with almost idential code.  If I leave off the total items, it just shows 1.

Comment: Aah in my prod code, I am loading the total-items dynamically, after a search, so it's null initially, your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **total-items** attribute for the the directive pagination :

```
<pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage">     </pagination>
```

Then you need to set the corresponding properties in your controller's scope :

```
$scope.currentPage = 4;
$scope.totalItems = 10; // For example.
$scope.itemsPerPage = 2;
```

You can find all the details on the documentation [for the pagination directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)